# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, authentication, kerberos

As the title states, I'm getting the following error when attempting to use a ASP.NET webapp:

`Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: 192.168.x.x]`

This is from the "Application" log on the SQL server. I currently have a clustered setup (using Microsoft Failover Cluster) although the second node has not been configured yet. I've tried configuring SPNs:

**setspn -L myserviceaccount**

```
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for <DN>:
        MSSQLSvc/*SQL.corp.*.local:1433
        MSSQLSvc/*SQL.corp.*.local
```

And indeed, SQL Server does register it correctly as per its logs:

`Message
The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/my.sql.fqdn ] for the SQL Server service.`

However, the query `SELECT auth_scheme FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid ;` returns `NTLM` and not `Kerberos`. I've restarted the server a few times to no avail. SQL Server runs under a domain user account with the appropriate delegation privileges.

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

I was successfully able to get the SQL Server to use "Kerberos" as per the above query, but I'm still having no luck getting the IIS level to work.

Comment: Are you using Basic Auth, or Windows Auth, on the website? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957443/web-app-getting-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon

Comment: Windows Auth. Even the "example" asp code has the same issue.

Comment: OK - sounds like the second answer covers your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as the "double hop" issue between SQL Server and IIS. It looks like you may not have trusted the IIS server for delegation.

[Here's a good checklist of things](http://blogs.technet.com/b/taraj/archive/2009/01/29/checklist-for-double-hop-issues-iis-and-sql-server.aspx) to do when setting up SQL Server with IIS using Kerberos.

[Here's a great primer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx) on the condition. The anonymous login is a give-away of the problem.

Comment: That's what it ended up being. Even after following the guides I wasn't able to get it "fully" working. After messing with some `Web.config` files I was eventually able to get it working. I even had it trying logging on as `domain\pcname$` before it started working properly...