# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql-server, authentication

Hi I get this error when connecting to SQL Server remotely from a website.
I checked the SQL Server logs and get the error:

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed
```

The SQL Service account is running as LocalSystem. From what I have read, SQL Server service automatically adds this account to SPN on startup.

TCP/IP is also enabled on the SQL Server.

Any ideas on what I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is almost always a Kerberos issue, due to an error somewhere along the way of setting up the SPNs.  See: [Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52511/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon-reason-token-based-server)

One easy to make, but harder to find, problem is to have *duplicate SPNs* on your network.

If that might be your problem, read the following post to help you find the duplicate: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/searching-for-duplicate-spns-got-a-little-easier)

A code snippet from that link:

```
setspn -q MSSQLSvc/mymachine.mydomain.com:1433 
CN=MYMACHINE,OU=Workstations,DC=mydomain,DC=com 
        MSSQLSvc/mymachine.mydomain.com:1433 
        HOST/MYMACHINE 
        HOST/MYMACHINE.MYDOMAIN.COM
```

Comment: What account should be registered for SPN? The LocalSystem account on SQL Server?

Comment: No it is the computername, such as: MyComputer123.domain.sub.net

Comment: I tried this but got error... C:\>setspn -S http/mymachine.domain.com

Missing parameter: accountname.